# How to join three tables in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, database-design

I have my records set up as follows

```
Subscription: id, plan_id                 <- belongs to plan
Plan: id, role_id                         <- belongs to role
Role: id, name
```

Given this data

```
Subscription: id: 1, plan_id: 5
Plan: id: 5, role_id: 10
Role: id: 10, name: 'Gold'
```

I'm trying to write a join so that I can find subscriptions based on their associated roles, i.e.:

> Subscription.joins(:plan).joins(:role).where("roles.name = ?", 'Gold')

But this approach doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you have proper associations then use this:

```
Subscription.includes(:plan => [:role]).where("roles.name = 'Gold'").first
```

You can also write the query manually:

```
Subscription.joins("INNER JOIN plans ON plans.id = subscriptions.plan_id
                    INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = plans.role_id").where("roles.name = 'Gold'").first
```

Comment: This is called nested joins, and you may even nest it three or more levels deep, like this: `.joins(plan: [role: :person])` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. I have a similar problem. But in my case a `plan` has many `subscriptions` but there is 1-to-1 relation between `plan` and `role` and so it gives me same `role_id` many times. Is there a way to get distinct `role_id` only? Let's say I get 10 records so 10 different `subscription_id`,  10 same `plan_id` and 10 same `role_id`. I want the distinct on either `plan.id` or on `role.id` but when I attach `.distinct()` at the end of the query above, it executes distinct on `subscription.id`. Is there a way though activerecord or do I have to run an each loop separately?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to find all the subscriptions for a given role, why not start with the role? Rails can take care of these "one step removed" associations if we configure them correctly.

```
gold_role = Role.where(name: 'Gold').first
gold_role.subscriptions
```

This is possible via [Rails' `has_many :through` relations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association). I think this is the correct setup for your models:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :role, through: :plan
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plans
  has_many :subscriptions, through: :plans
end
```